# Why this algorithm is O(n^2)

Tags: big-o

```
function multiply(x, y)
  Input: Two n-bit integers x and y, where y ≥ 0 Output: Their product
  if y=0: return 0 
  z = multiply(x, ⌊y/2⌋) 
  if y is even:
    return 2z 
  else:
    return x + 2z
```

As stated in my question, why is this function O(n^2)? This is an explanation from the book that above example belongs to :

> It must terminate after n recursive calls, because at each call y is halved—that is, its number of bits is decreased by one. And each recursive call requires these operations: a division by 2 (right shift); a test for odd/even (looking up the last bit); a multiplication by 2 (left shift); and possibly one addition, a total of O(n) bit operations. The total time taken is thus O(n^2), just as before.

Because of left shift and right shift of division by 2 and multiplication, I thought it would be bigger than O(n^2)..maybe n^3.

Comment: I think the book is talking time complexity - based on the number of iterations or depth of recursion. This is usually considered separate from the work done in each step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each of the operations right shift, test, left shift takes a fixed amount of time per bit, so it is done O(n) times per recursion. Remember that O(3n) is still O(n).

Since the entire function is applied recursively to each bit using the left shift, the previous O(n) steps are carried out O(n) times, making for a total complexity of O(n^2).

Comment: Thanks! That explains.

Comment: No problem. Be aware that this example is a bit contrived as Moby Disk says. While the explanation in your book makes sense, in reality most bitwise operations are really O(1) for modern processors.

Answer (score 1):

Is this a comp-sci textbook or a VLSI textbook?  Because the answer depends on the complexity of the operations y==0, y/2, 2z, x+2z, and "y is even".

As an applications developer, I consider those to be constant time operations so they are all O(1).  The Multiply function is then either O(log(Y)) or O(N) where N is the number of bits in Y.  Same thing.  Therefore, I conclude that this entire function is O(N).

Now, a computer engineer might argue that y/2 requires shifting N bits, and thus it is an O(N) operation.  There's probably some CPU out there that works that way.  Permit me to be absurd for a moment and argue that I could create an implementation for y==0 that takes O(N^47), thus this function is O(N^48).  :-)

In reality, any modern-day N-bit processor will do bit shifts of an N-bit number in parallel, so they really are O(1).  Maybe back on an 8088 this wasn't the case, but for any modern design that would be true.  So in practicality I argue this is O(N) not O(N^2)